# How to do search Functionality after parsing the data in ListView in android?

Tags: android-searchmanager

I am making an small application in android. In this I parsed the XML data with SAX parser in ListView Now the Parsed data is shown in the list. Now I want to do search Functionality in this means for example I have to made searchable functionality on one of the Tag value coming from XML file (example I have one value of **book name** )so I have to do functionality on book names when user write the book in the text field the search functionality the search buttons do the the searching.